# watchOS: CBCentralManager.state is always .unauthorized

Tags: bluetooth, watchos, cbcentralmanager

I am trying to use `CBCentralManager` in watchOS to scan for BLE devices.
I use the following code to start the scanning process:

`centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])`

This causes the following function to be called (as expected):

`internal func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {`

Problem: `central.state` is always `.unauthorized`

I have included `Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description` and `Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description` in info.plist for both the watchApp and watchAppExtention.

Is there something else that I should be doing (eg, include something in the entitlement file)? My app is not a peripheral; it is supposed to be in the "central" mode in foreground (not background).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
The privacy permissions in the `info.plist` must be placed in the iOS app (not the watchOS app). Then make a dummy request in the iOS app using the following code and users gets pop up that asks for Bluetooth access permission with the reason that you've provided in the `info.plist`.